# How Can I Exit Thread, When My UI Get Close Input in MFC

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stl, mfc

I am making some program with 'MFC'.

When A button is clicked, the Message handler makes new thread for work.

On Work, User Can Push B Button to exit the app.

In thread which is made by A button, it is using the C class that I made.

The class dynamic allocate some resources on work.

When B Button pushed, I want to de-allocate the resources before my app die.

How Can I do this? Help Please!!! :)

```
void CMyDlg::On_A_BnClicked() {  // do the job button
    ...
    AfxBeginThread(MyThread, (LPVOID)this);
    ...
}
UINT CMyDlg::MyThread(LPVOID arg) {
    ...
    MyCClass mcc;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        ...
        mcc.init(file_name);
        mcc.do_somethin();
        mcc.deinit();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
void CMyDlg::On_B_BnClicked() {  // close button
}
```

```
void MyCClass::init(file_name) {
    mFileClass.Open(file_name, CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite);
    // and so on
    ...
}
```

If User push B Button When 'do_somethin' method is doing in MyThread.

How Can I Exit MyThread after MyCClass Object's deinit() method?

I thought a way that Create Event in B Button Handler, then post message to MyCClass

So that I can deinit all of resources in MyCClass's message handler.

But It seems not work. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General mechanism:
Your working thread (WT) should have a protected data member `bool bRunning = true` (by default), a member function `Exit()` that sets `bRunning = false`. WT loop checks `bRunning` regularly & abort on `false`. When you create WT, keep its handle (let's say `hWT`), and before application exit, call `hWT->Exit()`.

--

In the case that it may take long time for WT to exit, add a synchronization mechanism. Kind of an example:

```
// WT.h

public:

int Run();

void Exit() // ** Assume that only main-thread call this, once. **
{
    std::mutex m_dummy_mutex;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(m_dummy_mutex);

    TRACE("WT state switched to not-running.\n");
    m_bRunning = false; // <-- (1)

    TRACE("Wait for WT stopped notification...\n");
    // (It may happen that the receiver wakes up, although no notification happened.)
    bool rv = m_stopped.wait_for(guard, std::chrono::seconds(5), // <-- (2)
               [this]() {return (m_pResource == nullptr); });
               // 'Spurious Wakeup' mitigation with lambda predicate.

    #ifdef _DEBUG
    if (rv)
        TRACE("WT stopped notification - Recieved.\n");
    else
        TRACE("WT stopped notification - Timeout expired.\n");
    #endif
}

protected:

std::condition_variable m_stopped;
bool                    m_bRunning = true; // Running until Stop().
CResource             * m_pResource = nullptr;
```

In WT loop:

```
// WT.cpp

int CWT::Run()
{
    m_pResource = new CResource; // Let's say CResource is your Resource.

    while (m_bRunning)
    {
        // Do something ... (May take time. Check regularly m_bRunning to abort.)

        if (!m_bRunning)
        {
            delete m_pResource;
            m_pResource = nullptr;
            m_stopped.notify_one(); // <-- (3)
            TRACE("WT stopped. Main-thread notified.\n");
            continue;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

- Instead of new/delete, it is better to use C++ smart-pointers.

Comment: If I did it then I have to wait the end of `do_somethin()` method that is doing when User click the B button (It is a possible scenario, because the `do_somethin()` method takes time a lot) '0' I want to exit app immediately with pushing close button. :)

Comment: @hslee , I added "kind of" a solution for that problem.

Comment: I coded with your first advise. Of course, There are some delay. But alternatively, I made waiting UI for User during waiting time. Thank you for your comments. :-)